# Why is std::tr1::unordered_map slower than a homegrown hash map?

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I wrote a basic program that takes strings and counts the incidences of unique ones by inserting them into a string->integer hash map.

I use std::tr1::unordered_map for the storage, templated for a custom hash function and a custom equality function.  The key type is actually `char*` rather than the too-slow `std::string`.

I then changed the same code to use a very, very simple hash table (really an array of {key, value} structures indexed by hash) with a power-of-two size and linear probing for collisions.  The program got 33% faster.

Given that when I was using tr1::unordered_map I presized the hash table so it never had to grow, and that I was using exactly the same hash and comparison routines, what is tr1::unordered_map doing that slows it down by 50% as compared to the most basic hash map imaginable?

Code for the hash map type I'm talking about as "simple" here:

```
typedef struct dataitem {
    char* item;
    size_t count;
} dataitem_t;

dataitem_t hashtable[HASHTABLE_SIZE] = {{NULL,0}}; // Start off with empty table

void insert(char* item) {
    size_t hash = generate_hash(item);
    size_t firsthash = hash;
    while (true) {
        hash &= HASHTABLE_SIZE_MASK; // Bitmasking effect is hash %= HASHTABLE_SIZE
        if (hashtable[hash].item == NULL) { // Free bucket
            hashtable[hash].item = item;
            hashtable[hash].count = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (strcmp(hashtable[hash].item, item) == 0) { // Not hash collision; same item
            hashtable[hash].count += 1;
            break;
        }
        hash++; // Hash collision.  Move to next bucket (linear probing)
        if (hash == firsthash) {
            // Table is full.  This does not happen because the presizing is correct.
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "homegrown" hash map?

Comment: @Nawaz: I wrote it myself in around 20 lines of C.

Comment: @Borealid:  So if you don't post your code, how can we say why `std::tr1::unordered_map` is slower than your "homegrown" hash map?

Comment: @Nawaz: I've posted the code.  But, like I said, it's just the simplest possible trivial little hash table.  Keep in mind that the tr1::unordered_map was also presized to fit the data.

Comment: What does the profiler say about CPU time consumed when testing?

Comment: @Andy Finkenstadt: callgrind shows me time inside the tr1::unordered_map functions.  Doesn't really tell me anything about what it's actually doing.  What type of profiler would show me WHY the functions take longer as opposed to just WHAT functions are consuming time?  Note that there are no rehashes and no mallocs on either profile.

Comment: Are we talking about Microsoft's version? 'Cuz I've obtained higher performance in my app by writing drop-in replacement vector and hashtable classes. Their STL code is virtually indecipherable so I can't quite say why. But I don't think I got a full 33% improvement.

Comment: @Qwertie: gcc 4.5.1 with whatever corresponding glibc.

Comment: BTW, if you can come up with a hash function with many terms, a simple modification could do better than linear probing here. Hash with the first term only, if collision, insert the second term, etc. and eventually fallback to linear probing when you run out of terms. Just an idea.

Comment: @blais: Sounds like cuckoo hashing to me.

Answer (score 12):

I wish to extend @AProgrammer answer.

Your hash map is simple because it is custom tailored to your need. On the other hand `std::tr1::unordered_map` has to fulfill a number of different tasks, and do well in all case. This require a mean-performance approach in all cases, so it'll never be excellent in any particular area.

Hash containers are very special in that there are many ways to implement them, you chose Open-Addressing, while the standard forces a bucket approach on the implementors. Both have different trade-offs, and this is one reason why the standard, this time, actually enforced a particular implementation: so that performance do not change dramatically when switching from one library to another. Simply specifying Big-O complexity / amortized complexity would not have been enough here.

You say that you instructed the `unordered_map` as to the number of finals elements, but did you change the load factor ? Chaining is notoriously "bad" (because of the lack of memory locality) in case of collisions, and using a smaller load factor would favor spreading out your elements.

Finally, to point out one difference: what happens when you resize your hash map ? By using chaining, the `unordered_map` does not move the elements in memory:

- references to them are still valid (even though the iterators may be invalidated)
- in case of big or complex objects, there is no invocation of copy constructors

This is in contrast with *your simple implementation*, which would incur `O(N)` copies (unless you use linear rehashing to spread out the work, but this is definitely not simple).

It seems, therefore, that the choice for `unordered_map` was to smooth the *spikes*, at the cost of a slower average insert.

There is something **you** can do though: provide a *custom allocator*. By writing a specific allocator for your usecase, and allocate all its memory in one go (since you know how many objects will be inserted, and can have the allocator report how much memory is a node). Then allocate the nodes in a stack-like fashion (simple pointer increase). It should improve (somewhat) the performance.

Answer (score 6):

Your "homegrown hash map" is not a hash map at all, it's an intrusive hash set.
And that's the reason it's faster. Simple as that.

Well, actually intrusive hash set isn't exact either, but it's the closest match.

Comment: What is it about the above code that makes it not a hash map?

Comment: It's not a map because it doesn't map a key to a value. It just inserts keys into a hash *set*.

Answer (score 4):

In general comparing speed of components not build to the same spec isn't fair.

Without knowing exactly what you have measured -- which mix of operations on which load factor with which mix of present/absent data --, it is difficult to explain where the difference come from.

The TR1 of g++ solve collision by chaining.  This implies dynamic allocation. But this also gives better performance at high load level.

Comment: The benchmark in question was loads of random strings having random left-skewed lengths up to 9k characters, followed by a single iteration through all elements in the hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

Your "homegrown" hash map is faster<sup>1</sup> than `std::tr1::unordered_map` because, as you yourself said, your homegrown hash map is *"simple"* and it *doesn't handle checking if the hash table is full*. And possibly many things that you're not checking before operating on it. That may be the reason why your hash map is faster than `std::tr1::unordered_map`.

Also, the performance of `std::tr1::unordered_map` is defined by the implementation, so different implementation would perform differently speed-wise. You can see its implementation and compare it with yours, as that is the first thing you can do, and I believe, that will also answer your question to some extent.

<sup>1. I just assumed your claim to be correct, and based on it I said the above thing.</sup>

Comment: I would love it if this were the case, but I actually did put in a check for noting that the hash table is full in the production code I tested.  It simply consists of storing the first hash value for the item.  If we ever loop all the way around and get that hash again, the table is full.  Since the hash tables are presized to not need growth, whatever condition tr1::unordered_map uses for resizing will always be false, so the time complexity of that branch does not matter.  Do you have another case where the above code is "not checking before operating"?

Comment: I've updated the code in the question with the table-is-full check.